# Результат функции как продолжительность setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы функция getGameSound возвращала результат метода thisAudio.onloadedmetadata в getGameSound duration. 
Результат метода должен стать продолжительностью setTimeout.

```
    TheGunman.prototype.getGameSounds = function (action) {
    var audioTmpl = '<audio id=":action" src=":path:action:expansionSound" autoplay></audio>';
    var getAudio = audioTmpl.replace(/:action/gi, action).replace(/:path/gi, this.pathSound).replace(/:expansionSound/gi, this.expansionSound);

    this.GameObject.frame.append(getAudio);

    var thisAudio = document.querySelector('#' + action);


 // результат выполнения этого метода надо вернуть в функцию из которой вызывался getGameSound
    return thisAudio.onloadedmetadata = function () {
        return thisAudio.duration * 1000;
    }

};

TheGunman.prototype.startGame = function () {
    var __self = this;
    var duration = // длительность звука вернувшего из функции getGameSounds
       this.getGameSounds('intro');

        setTimeout(function () {
            __self.CreateNewEnemy();

        }, duration);
```

Comment: Если результат известен не сразу, то через callback/promise, как обычно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`Promise`](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise), пока это хорошее решение (лучше [`async/await`](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/), но это только в `ES2017` обещают).

```js
function start(){
  getTime().then(duration => {
    // Получаем значение времени после разрешения обещания (после вызова в нём resolve)
    // Через 4s исполняем код таймера (в данном случае, выводим надпись)
    setTimeout(() => console.info("Let's rock!"), duration);
  });
}

function getTime(){
  // Делаем что-то несомненно важное, если нужно...
  
  // Ожидание асинхронного кода (неизвестно когда произойдёт); решаем по современному: Promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Эмулируем ожидание через таймер на 1 секунду, ожидание может быть чего угодно
    setTimeout(resolve(3000), 1000); // 3s будут как возвращённое время
  });
}

start();
```